# Blank space on the right side of container after lowering resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have divs in rows inside of the container. When the size of the window changes so does number of divs in one row. But in place where use to be the div now I have blank space.

How could I make width of container fit to number of divs in a row?
Here is my code

HTML:

```
<select>
 <option value="12">6</option>
 <option value="16">8</option>
 <option value="24">12</option> 
</select>
<button>OK</button>
<div id='container'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
border-style: solid;   
float:left;

}
.square{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function(){
var br=0;
$('#container').html('');
var k=$('select').val();
br=k/4-1;
contained_divs = '';
for(var i=0;i<k;i++)
 {
    contained_divs += '<div class="square"></div>';

    if(i!=0 && i%br==0)
    {
        contained_divs += '<br>';
    }


}
$('#container').append(contained_divs);
});  
});
```

and [**jfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nrh1tzd1/4/)

Comment: Why not just make the width 480px?

Comment: because I want width to change with resolution

Comment: Then why are you using fixed layouts?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the window resize event.
Make sure use this in `$(document).ready` as well.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 480){
        $("#container").css("width","480");
    } else if(window.innerWidth < 480) {
        $("#container").css("width","380");
    /*And keep going till getting your result*/
    }
});
```